# PHP Session Upload Progress and fcgid

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I'm using Apache2.2/mod_fcgid/php5.4.3 and the upload progress does not show up in the session. I read that the php session upload progress feature will not work if php is loaded via fastcgi. Is that true? If so, what are the options for getting upload progress when using fastcgi?

Answer (score 2):

"[[mod_fcgi] reads the entire request body from the client before sending it to the application.](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestinmem)"

You should try using Nginx and PHP-FPM, which has support for "[Accelerated File Upload](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features#Accelerated_upload_support)", where your PHP code can run before the complete request is received by Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [mod_fcgi](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html) you could switch to [mod_fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html), which has the following [configuration option](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiConfig):

> -flush (none) Force a write to the client as data is received from the application. By default, mod_fastcgi buffers data in order to free the application as quickly as possible.